# Angularjs custom form elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to create a new type of form element ( should have the same behaviour: validate,value,etc), that has object as value.

For example, I need a "birtday element". When clicked, a popup with two selects for month and day are show. ( like a picker date). When I get the value I should get womething like that {month:8,day:21}. Also when submited to server, the data should be also sent multi-field.

Other use cases: personName ( firstName,lastName),  price(amount,currency).

How can I approach such task in AngularJs?

Examples, tutorials and docs I found, are far away from such a complex task.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service to hold the data (state) for your form like this

```
angular.module('myAppName').service('myFormService', ['$http', function($http){

    var formState = {
        FirstName: '',
        LastName: '',
        Birthday: null
    };

    // you may also want to put methods here like reset, save etc...
    function reset() { formState.FirstName = ''; etc... }
    function save() { $http.post(...); }

    // this will create a singleton and will remain active across all pages
    return {
        FormState: formState,
        Reset: reset,
        Save: save
    };

}]);
```

Then for the different parts to your form create directives like this

```
angular.module('myAppName').directive('birthdayPicker', ['myFormService', function(myFormService){

    function link(scope, element, attrs){

        // bind to this in your html
        scope.birthday = myFormService.Birthday
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/birthdayPicker.html',
        link: link
    };
}]);
```

In your template html file

```
<div>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="birthday" />
</div>
```

In your html file use your directive like so

```
<div>
    <div data-birthday-picker=""></div>
</div>
```

Now when you get ready to send your form state to the server you would simply do this
I would recommend putting this inside your form service in a save method

```
$http.post('/someUrl', myFormService.FormState).success(successCallback);
```

A few extra tips

- use require.js to help with module separation and to remove the headache of correctly ordering your script tags
- make sure you are testing your code, a test first approach will often reveal the best design

Comment: Mark: where do I put the logic of setting sub-fields of the element (month,day)? Do I need to inject each form service For each form i use that kind of field? What happens if i have two fields of the same type in the same form?

Comment: in your directive you would just bind them like this  <input type="text" data-ng-model="day" />  <input type="text" data-ng-model="month" />   however you don't have to use a text field, you could bind to two dropdowns